Wordpress - Checkbox required doesn't validate
I am trying to make a checkbox required in order to proceed to the next page. I am develping inside of functions.php. Does functions.php not allow the required inside of regular HTML tags?
Here is what I have so far:
add_action('web_hook', 'test_button', 10);

function test_button() {
    // required does not seem to do anything
    echo '
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Check1" id="Check1" value="Check1" value="yes" required> 
        <label>this is the first checkbox</label>
    </form>
    ';

// test to see if page direct stops if checkbox not ticked
echo '<a href="https://someurl.com" >Click this to proceed</a>';


    echo '<br>';
}


Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79198237/wordpress-checkbox-required-doesnt-validate.

@Caleb you provided link to this question

Sorry. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/427591/how-to-make-checkbox-required

The PHP is there to generate the HTML. Let's look at correct HTML with a required checkbox. I think you were missing a submit button. That will handle the form.
If you want to handle page unload (like when clicking a link) it's a bit different you would need to handle the event beforeunload using javascript.
With both methods combined, user would need to check the checkbox in order to proceed or cancel.


function isChecked() {
  return document.getElementById("Check1").checked
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(ev) {
  if (!isChecked()) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.returnValue = '';
  }
})
<form>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Check1" id="Check1" value="Check1" value="yes" required>
  this is the first checkbox</label>

  <button>continue</button>
</form>

<a href="https://example.com">outer link</a>




Thank you! I only have to ask, is there any way to display it as an alert box, and not simply a way for the user to leave the site?

I didn't understand what you mean. But you can't change the default behavior for the beforeunload dialog
